# Need help wrapping third party to a bundle

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle

I need to use these two packages in my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator;

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.InetAddressValidator;
```

So I need to grab Apache commons-validator 1.4.0 and make it a bundle.

For that I've created a new maven project, consisting only in one POM file, where the POM contains the following: http://pastebin.com/qdbyuvhc

However, when I compile this project, the resulting bundle manifest will start importing new stuff. Check the Import-Package tag of the generated MANIFEST.MF here: http://pastebin.com/71LxAZ7Z

I would expect it to import nothing and be self-contained. I hate this stuff when working with OSGi, including 3rd party dependencies is very hard:(

How can I make this bundle self-contained?

Answer (score 2):

Commons validator already seems to be a bundle. [Check on maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-validator%7Ccommons-validator%7C1.4.0%7Cjar).
Besides that there is also a [commons validator bundle from servicemix](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.servicemix.bundles%7Corg.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-validator%7C1.3.1_2%7Cbundle). The [servicemix bundle source code](http://servicemix.apache.org/developers/source/bundles-source.html) can help you do your own wrapping if you need it at some point.

Comment: The thing is that the jar needs to be OSGi-fyed = jar + OSGi metadata, which envolves repackaging. According to Apache Commons Wiki, there is such repackage (OSGi bundle) but only until version 1.3.1. SpringSource Repository seems to have it available.

Comment: Yes, the version I need is 1.4.0. I've tried 1.3.1 before and they miss the classes I use. However their source code is very interesting, they are forced to refer direct dependencies but the way they manage transitive dependencies is a novelty for me, I'll need to look at it closer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is to add this bundle as maven dependency to your project's pom file, here is the dependency snippet (from [SpringSource Repo](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.commons.validator&version=1.3.1)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also if you have our own Artifacts Repository, I recommend you to download the jar of the dependency from [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.commons.validator&version=1.3.1) and add it to Artifacts Repository also (e.g. Nexus or other). Then add SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository to your Artifacts Repository Proxy Repositories.

**Quick FAQ**

**1. But can I use the commons.validator 1.4.0?**

No, you can't, the current repackage available of the apache.commons.validator is of the version 1.3.1.

**2. Is there a workaround if I really want to use the version 1.4.0?**

Maybe! You can try your luck with repackaging, this [page](http://www.codetrails.com/blog/osgi-ify-your-tools-jar) seems to point you on a good to way to achieve this. The post on the linked page seems to try to use http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/ to create a bundle that would wrap your **apache.commons.validator-1.4.0.jar**.

Comment: Yep I really need 1.4.0. I'll try tycho.

Answer (score 1):

you can control what import or not in the result manifest just adding this into the instructions tag:

```
<Import-Package>!DontWantThisPackage</Import-Package>
```

Btw, some of commons-validator dependencies are already bundle, so don't make sense to embed then in your bundle.

In order to embed dependencies I suggest you to add them directly in your bundle dependencies (instead to use the transitive ones)